# Powertools DragDropUploader Uploaded 0 file. Number of failures error

Tags: cme, powertools

We've installed Powertools and are trying to use the DragDropUploader.  At first we were missing the `TemporaryFiles` folder as the error in the Event Viewer showed.  After creating it and setting full permissions to MTSUser, the images do get uploaded into this folder, but it stops there with the CME showing this error: `Uploaded 0 file. Number of failures error`

[image]

The Event Viewer logs don't show anything at all.

On a separate note, the BulkImageUploader powertool isn't working either.  It just hangs at the loading screen with the bar at 100%.  I suspect the two issues are related.  What could be the cause?

Comment: Does the bulk uploader use MTSUser or the current user? Could it be permissions and/or a naming conflict?

Comment: @NickoliRoussakov is there any (additional) info in the Chrome console perhaps?

Answer (score 5):

I had some similar problems with the first release. I ended up creating a new installation from the sources. Both uploaders work fine for me now.

Did you use the installer or make your own installation?